# Hide fields from "address_field Module" form

Tags: users, entities

I have a site using **Profile2** with **address_field** Module; and I would like to prevent users from filling out the follwing fields:
Address 1
Address 2
ZIP Code
Country

The goal is is only to be able to fill only CITY AND STATE; (e.g. Orlando, FLORIDA)

Thanks.

J.M.

Answer (score 2):

in a hook_form_alter() add:

```
   hide($form['field_address']['und'][0]['street_block']);
```

you can use dpm($form['field_address']['und'][0]) to get the name of the city, and country fields.

You could also use CSS to hide the fields but I ran into problems where browsers prefilled those fields. It's better to hide it with a hook.

Comment: you solution is good (y)

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the address-hide-country.inc file in the address module. It has given a good example of how to hide the country field.

Also there is an example module for how to create an address field plugin to create custom plugin to act on the address field.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the country by checking the "Hide the country when only one is available" box in the field settings for your address field. Then you can add the following code to custom module to hide the Address1, Address2, and ZIP (where "MYMODULE" is the name of your custom module, "MYPROFILETYPE" is the machine name of the profile type you are altering, and MYFIELD is the name of your address field):

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_form_profile2_edit_PROFILE_NAME_form_alter()
 */
function MYMODULE_form_profile2_edit_MYPROFILETYPE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state){
  //dsm($form['profile_MYPROFILETYPE']['field_MYFIELD']['und'][0]);
  hide($form['profile_MYPROFILETYPE']['field_MYFIELD']['und'][0]['street_block']['thoroughfare']);
  hide($form['profile_MYPROFILETYPE']['field_MYFIELD']['und'][0]['street_block']['premise']);
  hide($form['profile_MYPROFILETYPE']['field_MYFIELD']['und'][0]['locality_block']['postal_code']);
}
```