# Cant make postal code only required

Tags: 7, entities

I am using the adress field module and like to make only the postal code field required.
The rest of the fields i like to hide.

The hiding of the fields are no problem however i am having problems with making only the postalcode field required.
I can hide the whole field with:

```
<?php
 function my_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, $form_state,  $form_id) {                

  if ($form_id == 'user_profile_form') {

  $form['field_adress']['und'][0]['#required'] = TRUE;
      }
    }
      ?>
```

but then this is not working

```
$form['field_adress']['und'][0]['locality_block']['postal_code']['#required'] = TRUE;
```

What am i missing?
Without succes i have tried solutions as:
[In here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31580/hide-fields-from-address-field-module-form)
[and here](https://drupal.org/node/1010314#comment-4614950)

Comment: Did you spell "address" in `field_adress` incorrectly intentionally?

Comment: Yes sorry this might be confusing but i double checked for type errors and i couldn't find any. thanks for asking

Answer (score 1):

You can make the address field not-required and write a custom validate function to check for the postal code. Like this:

```
<?php
function my_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, $form_state,  $form_id) {                
  if ($form_id == 'user_profile_form') {
      $form['field_adress']['und'][0]['#required'] = FALSE;
      array_unshift($form['#validate'], '_my_postal_validate');
  } 
}

function _my_postal_validate(&$form, &$form_state) {
    if (strlen($form_state['values']['field_adress']['und'][0]['postal_code']) < 2) {
        form_set_error('field_address', t('You must enter a postal code'));
    }
}
?>
```

See [form_set_error](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_set_error/7) to set better form errors.

If you support non US addresses (without a postal code), make sure the postal_code is available or you'll get warnings.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I have tried your code however my netbeans and drupal seem to stumble over print_r.
Drupal 7 returns a parse error in this line....

Comment: print_r is a php function, it should not give any errors. I'll update my answer with the entire validate function, that should work for you

Comment: You're right i did not place you're first code right.
Thanks for you're update.
However with the first and second version i can still leave my fields empty.
It does not give the error...I have looked in previous examples on d.org to make only postal code field required. In there the field was specified as `($form['field_adress']['und'][0]['locality_block']['postal_code']);` Hiding a field for example city is not a problem using this, making one field required until now is...

Comment: The idea is to make the address field NOT required and do a custom validation for the postal code. The code above works in a clean drupal 7.28 with addressfield 7.x-1.0-beta5. What does not work for you?

Comment: I understand. I have tried your code with my adress_field on 'required' and 'not required'. If my field is required the code, for some reason doesn't become 'not required'. If let my adress_field unrequired i can leave all fields empty and still save my user profile. So now i have to find out why youre code is not working....I'll be posting.

Comment: Basic checklist: 1) clear caches, 2) check if your hook_form_alter is called by calling die() 3) check if your validate function is called by calling die()

Comment: i have limited php skills. Could you give a short example how to check calling die()

Comment: Change the first line to:
function my_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, $form_state,  $form_id) { die('test'); ...

Comment: The first function seems to be called as it resulted in a blanc page with test printed on it.
Using die() in the second function resulted in the normal profile page.

Comment: Add die('test') in the second function and then submit the form.

Comment: After submitting user profiles just displays as usual
Just read you're previous comments and you're code closely. In the Drupal UI i should set the field_addres unrequired. this way leaving the field for a validation. This way i will not get the red 'required asterisk is this right. I created a similar situation with validation module. I thought this was somehow confusing from a user perspective. Getting the required red asterisk got me to coding...

Comment: The line `$form['field_adress']['und'][0]['#required'] = FALSE;` overrides the Drupal field required setting. Double check for typos in function and field names, because I just tested it and my code works if you put it in a themes template.php of a new Drupal install.

Comment: couldn't find any typos.
For the time being i have made my postal_code field required with the validation module. Now looking for a nice way to let the user know this field is required. As there is no red asterisk sign.